# 3D games for Google Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm wondering if anyone out there has experience working on 3D games for Glass.  I'm working on a Unity game that is coming along nicely, but pushes the limits of the device pretty hard.  In fact, the game is cripplingly slow if you try to play while the device is plugged in (charging), and it drains the battery pretty quickly.

Another unfortunate glitch is that the Unity activity overrides the gesture input, so the swipe-down-to-close action isn't recognized.  I had to hack my own together but it's not perfect.

I'm wondering if these kinds of issues will prevent the app from seeing the light of day.  Has anyone else had any luck submitting 3D games to Google?  I don't see any 3D stuff on Glassware (except maybe the star maps), so I'm worried that this project is a non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

I published my Glass wrapper activity to GitHub.  In case anyone else wants to use Unity with Glass.

https://github.com/DefectiveStudios/glasswrapper